# Algorithm to offset a list of data

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a list of data as follows:

```
input = [1,1,1,1,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,5,5]
```

I would like to create an algorithm that is able to offset the list of certain number of steps. For example, if the offset = -1:

```
def offsetFunc(inputList, offsetList):
    #make something
    return output
```

where:

```
output = [0,0,0,0,1,1,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,2,2]
```

**Important Note**: The elements of the list are float numbers and they are not in any progression. So I actually need to shift them, I cannot use any work-around for getting the result.

So basically, the algorithm should replace the first set of values (the 4 "1", basically) with the 0 and then it should:

1. Detect the lenght of the next range of values
2. Create a parallel output vectors with the values delayed by one set

The way I have roughly described the algorithm above is how I would do it. However I'm a newbie to Python (and even beginner in general programming) and I have figured out time by time that Python has a lot of built-in functions that could make the algorithm less heavy and iterating. Does anyone have any suggestion to better develop a script to make this kind of job? This is the code I have written so far (assuming a static offset at -1):

```
input = [1,1,1,1,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,5,5]
output = []
PrevVal = 0
NextVal = input[0]
i = 0
while input[i] == NextVal:
    output.append(PrevVal)
    i += 1

while i < len(input):    
    PrevVal = NextVal
    NextVal = input[i]
    while input[i] == NextVal:
        output.append(PrevVal)
        i += 1
        if i >= len(input):
            break

print output
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

**BETTER DESCRIPTION**
My list will always be composed of "sets" of values. They are usually float numbers, and they take values such as this short example below:

```
Sample = [1.236,1.236,1.236,1.236,1.863,1.863,1.863,1.863,1.863,1.863]
```

In this example, the first set (the one with value "1.236") is long 4 while the second one is long 6. What I would like to get as an output, when the offset = -1, is:

1. The value "0.000" in the first 4 elements;
2. The value "1.236" in the second 6 elements.

So basically, this "offset" function is creating the list with the same "structure" (ranges of lengths) but with the values *delayed by "offset" times*.

I hope it's clear now, unfortunately the problem itself is still a bit silly to me (plus I don't even speak good English :) )
Please don't hesitate to ask any additional info to complete the question and make it clearer.

Comment: Can you add an example with offset=-2 also, please?

Comment: Of course. It would become: `output = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,3,3]`. Basically, let's say that the first "(-offset) sets of same values" (e.g. if offset = -2, the first 2 sets of same values) will become 0 while the remaining will have the same lenght, but the values of "-offset" (2) sets of values before.

Comment: And offset is always negative? Or a "positive" offset means to 'shift it' to the left instead to the right?

Comment: Offset is always negative for the scope of the algorithm, no worries about the to-left shift.

Comment: I suggest to operate in two steps: get a list of couples (lenght, value) and then shift the 'values'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
def generateOutput(input, value=0, offset=-1):
  values = []
  for i in range(len(input)):
    if i < 1 or input[i] == input[i-1]:
      yield value
    else:  # value change in input detected
      values.append(input[i-1])
      if len(values) >= -offset:
        value = values.pop(0)
      yield value

input = [1,1,1,1,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,5,5]
print list(generateOutput(input))
```

It will print this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2]
```

And in case you just want to iterate, you do not even need to build the list.  Just use `for i in generateOutput(input): …` then.

For other offsets, use this:

```
print list(generateOutput(input, 0, -2))
```

prints:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3]
```

Comment: I am very sorry but I have realized that the example I have used was misunderstandable. I've just edited the question, what I need is to actually shift back the elements (and not just their values) :)

Comment: It fits the (original) exmaple, but it never fitted the actual description of the problem. It would be wise to remove/update the answer.

Comment: It solves the problem for offset=-1 only. Though you can use it multiple times to solve for offset<-1 (with some modifications), it does not seem to be efficient.

Comment: Yeap, seems good to me. Thanks for making the effort to make a wrong answer a good one. +1.

Comment: @Alfe, thanks a lot for your code. It's very clear to me, it works perfect and solves my problem :)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ if speed matters for you, the `deque` implementation is about twice as fast.

Comment: @M4rtini not now, for the size, the kind and the number of lists I have to work on I think this solution is fine, it might be slower but I understand it a bit better. However I will have to work on something similar soon, I'm gonna implement your solution on that and realize which one is better. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, the idea behind M4rtini's solution and mine is the same—iterate through the original, keep a list of the values-to-come and yield the new list based on that.  The use of the `deque` with a fixed size in M4rtini's solution makes it more elegant than mine, so I'd prefer his version, actually ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Using `deque` as the queue, and using maxlen to define the shift length. Only holding unique values. pushing inn new values at the end, pushes out old values at the start of the queue, when the shift length has been reached.

```
from collections import deque

def shift(it, shift=1):
    q = deque(maxlen=shift+1)
    q.append(0)
    for i in it:
        if q[-1] != i:
            q.append(i)
        yield q[0]


Sample = [1.236,1.236,1.236,1.236,1.863,1.863,1.863,1.863,1.863,1.863]

print list(shift(Sample))
#[0, 0, 0, 0, 1.236, 1.236, 1.236, 1.236, 1.236, 1.236]
```

Comment: Yeah I like that use of `deque` with fixed size.

Answer (score 2):

My try:

```
#Input
input = [1,1,1,1,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,5,5]
shift = -1

#Build service structures: for each 'set of data' store its length and its value
set_lengths = []
set_values = []

prev_value = None
set_length = 0
for value in input:
    if prev_value is not None and value != prev_value:
        set_lengths.append(set_length)
        set_values.append(prev_value)
        set_length = 0
    set_length += 1
    prev_value = value
else:
    set_lengths.append(set_length)
    set_values.append(prev_value)

#Output the result, shifting the values
output = []
for i, l in enumerate(set_lengths):
    j = i + shift 
    if j < 0:
        output += [0] * l
    else:
        output += [set_values[j]] * l

print input
print output
```

gives:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def x(list, offset):
    return [el + offset for el in list]
```

Comment: I am very sorry but I have realized that the example I have used was misunderstandable. I've just edited it, what I need is to actually shift the elements and not just their values :)

Answer (score 1):

A completely different approach than my first answer is this:

```
import itertools
```

First analyze the input:

```
values, amounts = zip(*((n, len(list(g))) for n, g in itertools.groupby(input)))
```

We now have `(1, 5, 3, 2, 5)` and `(4, 2, 6, 3, 2)`.  Now apply the offset:

```
values = (0,) * (-offset) + values  # nevermind that it is longer now.
```

And synthesize it again:

```
output = sum([ [v] * a for v, a in zip(values, amounts) ], [])
```

This is way more elegant, way less understandable and probably way more expensive than my other answer, but I didn't want to hide it from you.